# I am trying to get the image full screen and landscape

Tags: graphics

I have generated a picture of chromosomes that I wish to make landscape:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{landscape}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,angle=90]{results.png}
\caption[short]{\textbf{Regions}}
\end{landscape}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you compile the code, it works but not fully. I was wondering if there is a simple modification. Thank you!

Comment: "not fully"? What do you mean? Do you have any error in the `log` file, the result is not what you expected? We cannot help you if you don't say more of the expected behavior and of your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{results.png}}
\caption[short]{\textbf{Regions}}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Another solution could be `sidewaysfigure` from `rotating` package:

```
\documentclass[12, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{results.png}
\caption[short]{\textbf{Regions}}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Is there a way to remove the frame?

Comment: @Johnathan yes. Suppress the `fbox` command, like in second example. As you can see from framed figura your scheme has some right margin. It won't be perfectly centered